# Mongoose Promise chaining fail to deleteMany

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For some reason my Promise chaining with Mongoose is not working.
Running it a second time works. I am curious what I did wrong.
Here's the code to recreate it.

Schema

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,   
tag:[{  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "tag" }]});

var tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
tag: String,
blog: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "blog" }]})
```

Create dummy data. 1 blog and 2 tag with reference objectid to the blog.

```
var Blog = require("../models/blog") //create your own ref
var Tag = require("../models/tag") //create your own ref

myBlog = new Blog({title: '1st Post'});
tag1 = new Tag({ tag: 'Tag 1' })
tag2 = new Tag({ tag: 'Tag 2' })

myBlog.tag.push(tag1);
myBlog.tag.push(tag2);
tag1.blog.push(myBlog);
tag2.blog.push(myBlog);

Promise.all([myBlog.save(), tag1.save(), tag2.save()])
        .then(() => {});
```

The goal of the code is to delete the blog objectid reference from both the tag, and if there's 0 elements of blog objectid, delete the tag as well.

```
let foundBlog
Blog.findOne({ title: '1st Post' })
   .then((blog) => {
       foundBlog = blog;
    })
   .then(() => {
       Tag.updateMany( //remove BlogID from Tags
           { _id: { $in: foundBlog.tag } },
           { $pull: { blog: foundBlog._id.toString() } }).exec()          
    })
    .then(() => { //remove any Tags with 0 BlogID
            Tag.deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } }).exec()
    })
```

Running this the first time did not delete my Tags. I believe Tag.deleteMany executed, but for some reason the Tags was not deleted even though there are 0 elements of blog objectid in both Tags, due to Tag.updateMany.

However, running the same code the 2nd time successfully remove both Tag.

Where did I go wrong? Clearly I must have either gotten my logic wrong or misunderstood how promises work? Any insights would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but try putting "return" before Tag.updateMany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want, [either give a callback to `exec()`, or return the query itself and call `then`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

This should work:

```
let foundBlog
Blog.findOne({ title: '1st Post' })
   .then((blog) => {
       foundBlog = blog;
    })
   .then(() => {
       return Tag.updateMany( //remove BlogID from Tags
           { _id: { $in: foundBlog.tag } },
           { $pull: { blog: foundBlog._id.toString() } });        
    })
    .then(() => { //remove any Tags with 0 BlogID
            Tag.deleteMany({ "blog": { $size: 0 } }).exec()
    })
```

Comment: Yes this solves it. Thanks alot, this really helped me to understand better how promises work.